# How can I make a post that belongs to a category or have specific tags, display different from the other single posts?

Tags: posts, tags, single

How can I make a  single post display different from the other single posts when I add it to a specific category.

example: I have a post that is in 3 categories: music, songs & video clips. I want every time that I add a post in category "songs", it will be displayed differently from all of the other default single posts that don't belong to the category songs. How can I do that? 
Also, can the same thing happen with tags too? Meaning, when I add to a post some specific tags can it change the template of the post?

Comment: when viewed as single. I have uprated the posts were my issues and questions were answered. What else more should I do?

Comment: i think you should really look at @milo answer... he check if the post is in a specific category the gives loads a different template / design for your post... You can also paste the single.php loop and the name of the category you want things to look different in pastebin and we could  help you a little bit more - bit milo  got a gr8 answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With CSS**: If your theme uses [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) on a containing element, you can target that element with the class `.category-songs` to control styling.

**With a template filter**: add a filter to [`single_template`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/single_template) and check the assigned categories for your `songs` category, and use the template `songs-single.php` if that category is found:

```
function wpse_check_single_categories( $template = '' ){
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach( $categories as $cat ):
        if( $cat->name == 'songs' ):
            $template = locate_template( array( "songs-single.php", $template ), false );
        endif;
    endforeach;
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpse_check_single_categories' );
```

Comment: To understand better, where do I have to write this function? In the beginning of songs-single.php or somewhere else?

Comment: @Alex the filter code would go in your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: If I want this template to be shown to more than 1 categories what do I have to do?
Also, can the same thing happen with tags too? Meaning, when I add to a post some specific tags can it change the template of the post?

Comment: @milo How would this work on the home page archives to style each post excerpt differently based on category?